# Write Log4J to database

Tags: database, spring, log4j

I am searching for some integration between Spring and Log4J, because I have  my Database connection in Spring:

```
<bean id="dataSourceOracle" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

and have a JDBCAppender in my Log4J like this:

```
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://server/db
log4j.appender.DB.user=user
log4j.appender.DB.password=pwd
```

But, I don't want to have 2 registers to the Database .... How can I use the Spring's Datasource inside my Log4J? there is a way to integrate this part?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend JDBCAppender class and override the "getConnection(Connection con)" method. There it says:

> "Override this to link with your connection pooling system."

Make a bean in your Spring file, configuring Log4j programmatically (f.e. see [here](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.de/2007/09/programmatically-configuring-log4j-and.html)), add the new appender and inject the pooled connection before.

Comment: Hi Stefan, It is the answer. Thank you very much!.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not the purpose of log4j to do what you want to do.**

But you can use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class to externalize the deployment details into a properties file, and access from bean configuration file via a special format – **${variable}**.

**Spring file**

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Create a properties file (**database.properties**), include your database details, put it into your project class path.

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password
```